# HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error Local IIS Web server

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, httphandler

I am trying to create my async HTTP handler on Visual Studio 2012.
I have spent about 10 hours to find out why the server keeps giving me "**HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error**" response. Poor old me.

And finally I found out that if I switch my Web server to Visual Studio Development Server. Everything works fine. And When I switch back to IIS Web server, it doesn't work again.
I tried to do some configuration with IIS manager. I just have no idea what I should do and how the localhost is linked to my development folder. There is no information about the port it's using and the folder it's mapping.

Can someone offer some help? What should I do to make IIS Web server work for me?
Thank you

Answer (score 23):

it is possible to fix this problem while keeping your app pool in integrated mode,

add the following markup to your application's **web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I got this error after upgrading from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2013 SP2 - and this was the exact solution for me.  Thanks!!

Comment: Where have you been my whole life? Thanks!